# Registering task from Gradle convention plugin after subprojects are configured

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a monorepo with multiple independent projects.

```
├── first-app
│   ├── adapters
│   ├── application
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── public-events
│   ├── settings.gradle.kts
│   └── spring-boot-configuration
├── second-app
│   ├── adapters
│   ├── application
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── settings.gradle.kts
│   └── spring-boot-configuration
├── build-conventions
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── settings.gradle.kts
│   └── src/...
```

Now I try to share some common build logic by extracting it to *convention plugins* (to `build-conventions` independent project, which gets linked to each app with `includeBuild("../build-conventions")`).

I had the following repeating code in the root `build.gradle.kts` of each independent project (`(first|second)-app`):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("jacoco-report-aggregation")
}

reporting {
    reports {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        val jacocoRootReport by registering(JacocoCoverageReport::class) {
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST)
            dependencies {
                project.subprojects
                    .filter { it.plugins.findPlugin("jacoco") != null }
                    .forEach { jacocoAggregation(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `jacocoRootReport` task's registration also adds each submodule having `jacoco` plugin to the list of `jacocoAggregation` dependencies (this is required for `jacocoRootReport` task in order to know which subprojects to inspect for collecting jacoco reports).

The aboove configuration works as expected until I extract jacoco aggregating task configuration into conventional plugin `jacoco-root-report-convention.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("jacoco-report-aggregation")
}

reporting {
    reports {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        val jacocoRootReport by registering(JacocoCoverageReport::class) {
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.UNIT_TEST)
            dependencies {
                project.subprojects
                    .filter { it.plugins.findPlugin("jacoco") != null }
                    .forEach { jacocoAggregation(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and try to apply it to the root of my project as:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("jacoco-root-report-convention")
}
```

Now there is no root report generated, because `.filter { it.plugins.findPlugin("jacoco") != null }` does not find any subproject matching given predicate.

The problem is that attempt to find `jacocoAggregation` candidates gets executed earlier than submodules are configured. Is there a way to establish the correct order? (first configure subprojects, and only then execute task registration code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to simply apply `jacoco-root-report-convention` after `subprojects`-block with `apply(plugin = "...")` syntax. Example:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("my-whatever-root-module-convention")
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "base-jvm-project-convention")
    apply(plugin = "dependencies-convention")
}

apply(plugin = "aggregated-reporting-convention") // <--------
```

In this case `aggregated-reporting-convention` will be applied after `subprojects` were configured.